# Xcode: preprocessor macros from configurations not seen in editor

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcconfig

Xcode seems to "build" for the editor warnings and errors with a configuration, which differs from the current scheme and thus does not pick up the preprocessor macros, which I define in xcconfig files.

I use a Standard.xcconfig files in which I define a preprocessor macro like this:

`GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) X_MY_FLAG=1`

I added new configurations "Debug Standard" and "Release Standard" in which I select the Standard configuration for the project (or the target).

I added a new scheme, which uses the "... Standard" variants of the configurations and select it in that dropdown in the top line of Xcode.

In `main.m` I use this snippet to test for the macro:

```
#if X_MY_FLAG == 1
#warning "Success. X_MY_FLAG picked up."
#else
#error "X_MY_FLAG not picked up"
#endif
```

Running a build (Cmd-B) produces a nice build output and as expected the warning message appears, not the error. However, in the editor window I also get the error information shown. (See screenshot below.) Seeing both cases of the `#if` getting evaluated is not what I want to see here.

[image]

So for the editor Xcode runs a "build", which does not use the configuration specified in the selected scheme.
Does anybody have a hint, how to fix this or what the actual underlying problem is?

Comment: It seems like Xcode **always** evaluates preprocessor expressions against "default" build configuration (`Debug` in my case). If you have the Configuration Set specified for any other configuration, Xcode builds it without issues, but at the same time checks for errors/warnings of `Debug` configuration and highlights them in the editor.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Thanks - that's just it. Fascinating :-) Do you happen to have an idea, whether the editor's association with the first configuration can be changed?

Comment: after playing around with it a little I could not deduce exact logic Xcode chooses the configuration for editor, but it seems to have something with naming, at least as the first criterion. Altering default configurations for a target doesn't change anything as far as I can see, the order they follow in the project (`*xproj`) file also don't do much.. Thus the "redundant" configuration needs either be removed or artificially de-prioritised (by renaming it for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode editor seems to always evaluate macro expressions for some "default" configuration in the Configurations list. As a result, if you have your Configuration Set file specified for any other configuration, it's not what editor window reflects (in this case `Debug` is the configuration editor parses preprocessor for):

[image]

It's silly but it seems you cannot alter this "default" configuration for the editor window, and what it does under the hood is simply sorting them with an unknown criterion.

I **assume** Xcode just takes `Debug` configuration when it's available or sort the list in alphabetical order and takes the first one from the sorted list of configurations otherwise, so renaming `Debug` to `Webug` for example, makes it a least preferred candidate for the macro evaluating by the editor window:

[image]